# Using pass in the middle of an function

Tags: python

Maybe a weird question, but can someone explain why this algorithm is generating any output at all at the first if statment?

```
X = "off"
    
    def ABC (X):
        toggle_option = X

    if X == "off":

        pass  

        print(ABC)

    def LMN (X):

        toggle_option = X        

        if X == "off":
            print("LMN")
            print("DEF")



ABC(X)
LMN(X)
```

OUTPUTS

```
<function ABC at 0x0000021889D35558>

LMN
DEF
```

This code is more of a curiosity piece than anything else.

I was just trying to see what would happen if you used pass right in the middle of a script.  Would it stop the entire program or just that part of it?

It only stops a part, but then it outputs a sort of error message.  The error message may or may not be useful.  But - to be even more curious - what if you wanted **to turn off error messages**?

I dont get what "<function ABC at 0x0000021889D35558>" even means, so it's not useful to me, although I like the fact that you can "pass" by certain areas of code.

Comment: As far as I remember, `pass`'s purpose is purely to fill space. As Python is indent based, a block with no content would make the interpreter panic. That's why it exists. It has no purpose other than to fill space. So it would make sense that that statement has no effect on the output of the progra,.

Comment: `pass` does not stop anything. it does just nothing (a no-op). what you are printing is a function. that is that that looks like... did you mean to `print("ABC")`?

Answer (score 1):

> [pass](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/pass.html) is a null operation -- when it is executed, nothing happens. It is useful as a placeholder when a statement is required syntactically, but no code needs to be executed.

Thus, it lets the function pass through to the next line, which is to do `print(ABC)`. As we can see, ABC is a function, or in memory, it is an object. What is is actually printing out is the function's reference in memory.

Answer (score 0):

As you may notice you are printing the function ABC itself in the line `print(ABC)` of the **ABC** function. You don't usually do this. You just call a function and print it's return value but you do not print the function itself.

The line `<function ABC at 0x0000021889D35558>` means the compiler is showing the memory block where the ABC function is currently stored on.

Answer (score 0):

You might be using pass in the wrong way. As far as I know, pass is only used to make the code syntactically correct. For example, if you want to make a for loop run but not do anything, like `for i in range(100): pass`, or in a if statement, like `if True: pass`.

And as the above answers tell, `<function ABC at 0x0000021889D35558>` only tells the location of the function in the computer memory.

However, if you want skipping ability in loops or if statement and want to skip current execution and go to next execution of the code block, you must use the `continue` keyword.

For example, in this case continue hampers the execution of current loop and returns to next execution:

```
>>>for i in range(5):
        if i == 3:
            continue
        print(i)

0
1
2
4
```

As you can notice, continue skips the execution of current iteration.More about the [continue](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_continue.asp) keyword.